# iOS App Lags between TabBar Clicks and Other Functions

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

My iOS app seems to be quite "laggy" between various functions (tabBar clicks, alert views, button presses, etc...) I have use the Xcode Leaks Instrument and do not see any memory leaks in the app. Is there something else I can do to narrow down what could be making the app feel "sticky"?

There is about a 1 second pause between various actions. This doesn't happen every time, but happens enough to notice. Also, if my app has been running in the background, when it comes to the foreground there is also a bit of a pause where the screen freezes up before the user can interact with app.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your viewWillAppear methods, if there are lot of things going on there, then there'll be a lag when you switch tabs. Instead if you shift your viewWillAppear operations into your viewDidAppear methods (assuming they don't effect the UX), then the lag will not happen

Comment: Thanks, there is actually a TON of stuff in my viewdidappear methods. There is also a lot in my viewdidload methods

Comment: would you recommend that I move stuff from viewdidload to viewdidappear?

Comment: viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear are fine, but operations in viewWillAppear should me minimized. Yes if its possible (doesn't mess with the UX) you should move stuff from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear